# How to merge 2 related questions with same possible answers

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, duplicate-questions

I found a question, lets call it [**Q1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100029/how-can-i-update-my-gui-score-one-point-at-a-time), and I answered it. Then I found the same question by the same user, lets call it [**Q2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100759/why-is-my-game-lagging-huge-when-i-call-a-method) , but worded slightly differently, with a little more effort, and it was answered by someone else. This someone else then answered Q1 with the same answer he/she put in Q2.

After reading all the comments and every detail, I believe both questions are essentially the same which should lead to the same answers.

I was thinking of flagging both posts to a mod, but I am not sure if that is the right step. I think the questions can be salvaged if they are merged into one. Can that be done?

---

The duplicate answer that was on both Q1 and Q2 was edited, check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25100794/revisions

It looks as if the two questions are diverging a bit now. Still, I was able to solve both questions in one answer. I would still appreciate a couple more eyes on both questions and some more insight.

Comment: Moderators can merge posts if you use a custom flag on one with a link to the other, but keep in mind that this is for use only when the two posts are 99% identical and answers valid on one are valid on the other as well.

Comment: @AstroCB good to know, thank you. At least the answers are not identical now. I'm going to keep watching both questions to see how they develop.

Answer (score 1):

Something resembling "merging questions" can really only be done by the OP of the questions or, as AstroCB [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267595/how-to-merge-2-related-questions-with-same-possible-answers/267596?noredirect=1#comment71709_267595),

> Moderators can merge posts if you use a custom flag on one with a link to the other, but keep in mind that this is for use only when the two posts are 99% identical and answers valid on one are valid on the other as well.

If Q2 is a duplicate of Q1 it should be closed as a duplicate. Users under 3k who cannot vote to close it as a duplicate should comment on it notifying other users of the duplicate and, if they are exact duplicates, flag it for moderator attention and link both questions.

Commenting on Q2 can also help by informing the user he can edit his previous question as it seems he does not know that feature exists.

However, **in this case the two questions are not duplicates** as one deals with *incrementing the score* and the other deals with *the lag between methods*. Don't be deceived by the similar code

Comment: What about the same answer in both questions? Even though OP is saying one is about lag, really he/she is having the same problem, the score update doesn't work the way he/she intends. In Q1 there is even a mention to the code that was later posted on Q2.

Comment: @FunctionR The two *questions* are different, seeking different answers. Therefore one is not a duplicate of the other. With that being said, I think it's okay for the user to link his answer on Q1 because it answers both questions. I think this is a very tricky case and could have been handled better by the OP, but each question may have value to separate audiences

Comment: I just saw the duplicate answer get edited, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25100794/revisions